# Windows 64bit shared dll Tesseract?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake, 64-bit, tesseract

I think it is possible but I just can’t get the following libs to build as 64 bit as they are built as part of the project but don't take on the bitness of the project (they are built using cppan/cmake):

> C:\Users\Bruce.cppan\storage\lib\amd64-msvc-19.0-32\Debug\pvt.cppan.demo.leptonica-master.lib
>   : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target
>   machine type 'x64'
>   4>C:\Users\Bruce.cppan\storage\lib\amd64-msvc-19.0-32\Debug\pvt.cppan.demo.gif-5.1.4.lib
>   : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target
>   machine type 'x64'
>   4>C:\Users\Bruce.cppan\storage\lib\amd64-msvc-19.0-32\Debug\pvt.cppan.demo.jpeg-9.2.0.lib
>   : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target
>   machine type 'x64'
>   4>C:\Users\Bruce.cppan\storage\lib\amd64-msvc-19.0-32\Debug\pvt.cppan.demo.openjpeg.openjp2-2.1.2.lib
>   : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target
>   machine type 'x64'
>   4>C:\Users\Bruce.cppan\storage\lib\amd64-msvc-19.0-32\Debug\pvt.cppan.demo.png-1.6.23.lib
>   : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target
>   machine type 'x64'
>   4>C:\Users\Bruce.cppan\storage\lib\amd64-msvc-19.0-32\Debug\pvt.cppan.demo.tiff-4.0.6.lib
>   : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target
>   machine type 'x64'
>   4>C:\Users\Bruce.cppan\storage\lib\amd64-msvc-19.0-32\Debug\pvt.cppan.demo.zlib-1.2.8.lib
>   : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target
>   machine type 'x64'
>   4>C:\Users\Bruce.cppan\storage\lib\amd64-msvc-19.0-32\Debug\pvt.cppan.demo.webp-0.5.1.lib
>   : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target
>   machine type 'x64'

To build as 64 bit:

1. Download and install Git, CMake and put them in PATH.
2. Download the latest CPPAN (C++ Archive Network https://cppan.org/) client from https://cppan.org/client/. CPPAN is a source package distribution system. Add CPPAN client in PATH too. (VS2015 redist is required.)
3. If you have a release archive, unpack it to tesseract dir. If you're using master branch run
4. git clone https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract tesseract
5. Run
6. cd tesseract
7. cppan
8. mkdir build && cd build
9. cmake .. -DSTATIC=1

Build a solution (`tesseract.sln`) in your Visual Studio version.
But I omit the `–DSTATIC=1` to get shared.

And I add a new configuration to the solution `x64` then I removed the hard coded `/machine:X86` from the `tesseract` and `tesseractmain` Additional Options in the Linker section.. but the libs built via the `cppan-dummy` project are still 32 bit.

Ideas?

Regards
Bruce

Comment: *"I think it is possible but I just can’t get the .libs:"* - please elaborate. What, specifically, do you think is possible? Which .libs can you not get?

Comment: 9. should be `cmake -DSTATIC=1 ..`.

Comment: But I don't want a static lib, I want a shared one.

Comment: I did it with -DSTATIC=1, and then added x64 build and then tried to build tesseract project as DLL as opposed to static lib.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of digging and learning about the MSVC build system, if you want a 64 bit shared .dll and .lib import library do this:

goto: https://github.com/peirick/VS2015_Tesseract

1. Clone the repo.
2. Change build_tesseract.bat to 64 bit Debug, don't forget to change call "%programfiles% (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
   14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64. Run build_tesseract.bat.
3. Specify TESS_EXPORTS in Preprocessors definitions of libtesseract project and also change it to .dll from .lib

This might be blindingly obvious to someone in the know, the difficult bit was working out the TESS_EXPORTS bit, only mentioned in code as far as I can tell and also using the above repo as it has all the dependencies. Props to peirick for setting up the repo and getting it all sorted.